# In List view how many list items can load in android

Tags: java, android

Normally in ListView are used in android,but how many items can totally load in list view ? Is it possible to load more than 10,000 items ?

Comment: Probably depends on the amount of memory available to the Android runtime

Comment: Yes. But the actual question should be - "Will I be able to show alll the 10000 items on my screen at the same time?". Lazy loading is preferred here.

Comment: The real question is "why on earth would any user want to browse through 10,000 items, instead of uninstalling this silly app".

Comment: You are a little tough @Kayaman, but I have to admit: I can't say you're wrong ;)

Comment: keep in mind that Android uses Flyweight pattern while displaying items inside ListView. Basically, you can keep 10 000 items representing your data model, but ListView itself gonna reuse few views and move them around when user is scrolling

Answer (score 3):

`ListView` itself will keep only a handful of view items in memory - those that are displayed on screen and possibly a few scrap items that are waiting to get recycled. `ListView` is not the limiting factor.

What is a limiting factor is the `Adapter` that feeds the `ListView`. If your adapter implementation keeps all data items in memory (e.g. an `ArrayAdapter`), then you're bound to hit a limit at some point. There are other adapters such as `CursorAdapter`s that load the data items on demand and don't keep everything in memory. They scale further.

Of course there's usability. `ListView` is practically unusable for browsing through a list of 10000 items. If you really have that much data to display, you have an user interface design problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ViewHolder` and `convertView` in `View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`. You can load more than 10,000 items with low memory usage.